# Custom DatePicker On EditText

Tags: android, datepicker, android-calendar, android-toast

I have 2 `EditText`.

When anyone click on a `EditText` datepicker is displayed to set date in `EditText`. so my coding for `EditText` is

```
    sdate.setOnTouchListener( new DrawableClickListener.RightDrawableClickListener(sdate)
                {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onDrawableClick()
                    {
                         MyDatePickerDialog(sdate);// put edit text view. 
                          return true;                     
                    }                   
                } );
                edate.setOnTouchListener( new DrawableClickListener.RightDrawableClickListener(edate)
                {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onDrawableClick()
                    {
                         MyDatePickerDialog(edate);// put edit text view. 
                         return true;                   
                    }
                } );
```

And my custom datepicker is

```
    private void MyDatePickerDialog(final EditText sdate) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sdgfdg" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                updateLabel();
            }

            private void updateLabel() {
                 String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy"; //In which you need put here
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

                    sdate.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
            }

        };

    }
```

But the problem is toast message is displayed but it dosent display datepicker

Comment: Where is the Dialog defined and set this listener on it ?

Comment: this is standard dialog picker @AnandMakwana import android.app.DatePickerDialog;

Comment: Where is show() method??

Comment: which show method @PiyushGupta if i remove method nd call direcly it displayed ....but which show method u need

Comment: @kibzorg i had implemented this but i have 2 edittext so i remove it tell me where to put this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a custom method only and you need to create a listener for `OnDateSetListener` to pass your `DatePickerDialog`

```
 private void MyDatePickerDialog(final EditText sdate) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sdgfdg" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     DatePickerDialog myPickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

            updateLabel();
        }

    },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        private void updateLabel() {
             String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy"; //In which you need put here
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
                sdate.setText(sdf.format(newCalendar.getTime()));
        }

    myPickerDialog.show();

  }
```

***NOTE:*** You can use `onClickListener` instead of `onTouchListener`.

Answer (score 1):

You have only created Listener of DatePickerDialog, not DatePickerDialog itself.

You have to do this:

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                getApplicationContext(), your Listener, year, month, dayOfMonth);
        datePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: yeh bro i had created it but i have 2 edittext so i remove it check it   http://pastie.org/10123331#2-3,17,19-20,24

Comment: You have to place this inside at end of your `MyDatePickerDialog()` function.