# How to display the date in string format on android Datepicker

Tags: android, widget

I had a date displayed as `05-12-2015` which is `MM-dd-yyyy` format on a `TextView`.
There was a button beside `Textview` which on clicking displays datepicker with current date which is `6th may`.
But I want the datepicker to display the `5th may` rather than current date.
Can anyone help me in solving this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190968/android-format-date-to-mm-dd-yyyy-from-datepicker

Comment: check it   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986113/custom-datepicker-on-edittext

Answer (score 1):

```
datePicker.init(2015, 12, 5, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy",Locale.getDefault()); 
                                        //  formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); 
formatter.setLenient(false);